# isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications returning NO even after turning on Notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

So we have a notification screen where users can customize the push notifications they want to receive. In this view controller, we check if [application isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications], we allow users to use the screen, else we show them the prompt that deep links to settings for the app. Now, what's happing is that certain users are complaining that this prompt never disappears even when they turn on in settings. They have sent us the screenshot of the screen, as well as device settings for the app. We have not been able to reproduce this issue. The view controller is directly checking against the OS flag, so there is not much scope of error there. Also we have gone through the code and haven't found anything. I am assuming that because of network issues, deviceToken is not getting delivered to the app. Not really sure what else might be going here. Appreciate any help or suggestions on this matter.